# iPhone - Removing New navigation

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am currently added a new view when a mapkit annotation is clicked:

```
-(IBAction)showDetails:(id)sender{


DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
dvc.title = ((UIButton*)sender).currentTitle;

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:dvc];
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController  animated:YES]; 
}
```

What I would like to do is on the new view is have a back button that will remove the view and display the mapkit again.

I am using a tabbar in the normal app. I have setup a button on the new view and tried this:

```
- (IBAction)backToMap:(id)sender {
UINavigationController *nc = [self navigationController];
NSLog(@"%@", [nc viewControllers]);
[nc popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
NSLog(@"%@", [nc viewControllers]);
[nc popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
NSLog(@"Close");
}
```

But it doesn't make any visual difference.

Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dismiss this modal viewController:

```
- (IBAction)backToMap:(id)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay Mark you can try with

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```